# How to use UDFeatureAnnotator in Stanford Corenlp?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

Does anyone know how to use UDFeatureAnnotator and WikiDictAnnotator in java Stanford CoreNLP.

The official documentation does not explain how to use these annotators.
https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/udfeats.html

**Update**

I got universal dependency annotator(UDFeatureAnnotator) working using *CoreNLP server*, but when I try to use WikiDictAnnotator(annotator name: "entitylink"), it gives me the following error.

```
edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading$ReflectionLoadingException: Error creating edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full stack trace.

Comment: Actually this error is the output of corenlp server. I get this single line when I try to hit the corenlp server with ‘entitylink’ annotation.

Comment: My guess is you don't have the joda-time.jar in your CLASSPATH when you are starting the server.

Comment: You need to have all of the jars that come with the distribution or in the lib directory when running the server, if you are missing something you will probably get an error.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp , thanks for the help.I resolved the issue with udfeats. But, could you point out what jar is needed for WikiDictAnnotator? I have downloaded the entire coreNLP server which comes with all the jars.

Comment: You need to get the English and English (KBP) jars also located on this page: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

Comment: Great.. thanks will try that.